# QuickSort - 3 pivot choosing methods via factory

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, design-patterns, multithreading

I'm happy to hear thoughts and ideas on structure/performance/testing/whatever and multi-threading, which I haven't gotten into yet with Python.

[Latest code here](https://github.com/OferSheffer/Review_Stanford_Algorithms/tree/master/src/P01W02Q01). Assignment file and a few test files included in the folder.

```
import sys
import unittest
from copy import deepcopy


class PivotMaker:
    pass


class PivotFirstElement(PivotMaker):
    """returns the first element index as the pivot"""

    def __init__(self, name="Question 1", pivoting_method="First Element"):
        self._name = name
        self._pivoting_method = pivoting_method

    def get_pivot(self, A, start, end):
        self._pivot = start
        return self._pivot


class PivotLastElement(PivotMaker):
    """returns the last element index as the pivot"""

    def __init__(self, name="Question 2", pivoting_method="Last Element"):
        self._name = name
        self._pivoting_method = pivoting_method

    def get_pivot(self, A, start, end):
        # assign last element's index to _pivot
        self._pivot = end-1
        return self._pivot


class PivotMedianElement(PivotMaker):
    """
    returns the median (from first, middle, last) element index as the pivot
    """

    def __init__(self, name="Question 3", pivoting_method="Median Element"):
        self._name = name
        self._pivoting_method = pivoting_method

    def get_pivot(self, A, start, end):
        n = end-start
        # mid_index:
        if n <= 2:
            self._pivot = start
            return self._pivot
        # else: n > 1:
        #     odd elements, e.g. 5 [0,1,2,3,4], mid_index=2 (n-1)/2
        #     even elements, e.g.4 [0,1,2,3], mid_index=1 (n-1)/2
        mid_index = start+(n-1)//2
        p_elements = [A[start], A[mid_index], A[end-1]]
        midean_value = sorted(p_elements)[1]

        # pivot=median index
        for i, p_element in enumerate(p_elements):
            if midean_value == p_element:
                self._pivot = [start, mid_index, end-1][i]
        return self._pivot


class PivotDirector():
    """Director"""
    def __init__(self, pivot_getter):
        self._pivot_getter = pivot_getter

    def get_pivot(self, *args):
        """
        get_pivot(A, start, end)
        Output: pivot_index
        """
        return self._pivot_getter.get_pivot(*args)

    def get_pivot_maker_data(self):
        return self._pivot_getter._name, self._pivot_getter._pivoting_method


def swap(A, index_1, index_2):
    """swap between two members of array A"""
    if index_1 == index_2:
        return
    # else: index_1 != index_2
    temp = A[index_2]
    A[index_2] = A[index_1]
    A[index_1] = temp


def partition(A, start, end, pivot_index):
    """
    Input: array A[start:end]
    Output: index of pivot once partition is complete
    Side effect:
        A[start:end] is divided into:
        "smaller than pivot","pivot","larger than pivot"
    """
    if end-start < 0:
        raise ValueError
    if not (start <= pivot_index <= end):
        raise ValueError

    # subarray with single or no elements
    if end-start <= 1:
        return start

    # else: subarray with more than 1 element
    # place pivot element at the start
    swap(A, start, pivot_index)
    pivot = A[start]

    # partition (iterate over j, bucket 'smaller'/'larger'-than-pivot values)
    i = start+1
    for j in range(start+1, end):
        if A[j] <= pivot:    # if A[j] > p, do nothing
            swap(A, j, i)
            i += 1
    swap(A, start, i-1)
    return i-1


def quick_sort(A, start=0, end=None, pivot_director=None):
    # TODO: test different types of input for this arg setup
    """
    Input:
    array A, start(default=0), end(if default=None := len(A))
    pivot_director - used to get_pivot() via external factory method.
    Output: comparisons (# of times elements were compared during sorting)
    Side Effect: A is sorted.
    """
    if end is None:
        end = len(A)

    n = end - start
    if n <= 1:
        return 0    # base case, array of length 1 [or len(input)==0]
    else:
        # TODO:
        pivot_index = pivot_director.get_pivot(A, start, end)

        # first question: always choose pivot = 0 [first element]
        # pivot_index = start

        # Partition A around pivot, fix comparison count
        comparisons = n-1
        pivot_index = partition(A, start, end, pivot_index)

        # Input: 1st and 2nd partitions of current sub-array
        x = quick_sort(A, start, pivot_index, pivot_director)
        y = quick_sort(A, pivot_index+1, end, pivot_director)
    return comparisons+x+y


class QuickSortTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `quick_sort.py`"""

    def test_swap(self):
        A = [2, 3]
        swap(A, 0, 1)
        self.assertEqual(A, [3, 2])

    def test_partition(self):
        A = []
        pivot_index = partition(A, 0, 0, 0)
        self.assertEqual(A, [])
        self.assertEqual(pivot_index, 0)

        B = [3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
        pivot_index = partition(B, 0, 5, 2)

        """
        [3, 5, 2, 1, 4] - original input array
        [2, 5, 3, 1, 4] - swap pivot with first
        [2, 5, 3, 1, 4] - compare first with 5, and then with 3 (no change)
        [2, 1, 3, 5, 4] - swap pos[1] with '1', advance index to 2
        [2, 1, 3, 5, 4] - compare first with 4 (no change)
        [1, 2, 3, 5, 4] - swap pos[0] with index-1, return index-1=1
        """
        self.assertEqual(B, [1, 2, 3, 5, 4])
        self.assertEqual(pivot_index, 1)

        # TODO: more partition tests

    def test_quick_sort_with_basic_lists(self):
        """
        Are basic lists sorted correctly
        with output = # of comparisons?
        """

        # TODO: add assert tests for input types
        pf = PivotFirstElement()
        pd = PivotDirector(pf)

        A = []
        comp0 = quick_sort(A, pivot_director=pd)  # empty list input

        self.assertEqual(A, [])
        self.assertEqual(comp0, 0)

        A = [1]
        comp1 = quick_sort(A, pivot_director=pd)  # single element
        self.assertEqual(A, [1])
        self.assertEqual(comp1, 0)

        B = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
        comp2 = quick_sort(B, pivot_director=pd)  # even length
        """
    '1' [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]  - 5 comparisons
    '3'    [3, 5, 2, 4, 6]  - 4 comparisons
           [3, 2, 5, 4, 6]  - switch places
           [2, 3, 5, 4, 6]  - place pivot
    '2'    [2]              - 0 comparisons
    '5'          [5, 4, 6]  - 2 comparisons
                 [4, 5, 6]  - place pivot
                 [4]        - 0 comparisons
                       [6]  - 0 comparisons
                            - Total = 5+4+2=11
        """
        self.assertEqual(B, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        self.assertEqual(comp2, 11)  # expected comparisons for pivot = 1st

        C = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3]
        comp3 = quick_sort(C, pivot_director=pd)  # odd length, duplicate value
        """
    '1' [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3]  - 6 comparisons
    '3'    [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3]  - 5 comparisons
    '3'    [3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]  - partitioned
    '3'    [3, 2]              - 1 comparison
    '4'             [4, 6, 5]  - 2 comparisons
    '6'                [6, 5]  - 1 comparisons
                               - Total = 6+5+1+2+1=15
        """
        self.assertEqual(C, [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        self.assertEqual(comp3, 15)  # expected comparisons for pivot = 1st

        # TODO: implement testing for all pivot types.

    def test_pivot_median_element(self):
        pf = PivotMedianElement()
        pd = PivotDirector(pf)

        A = []    # empty list input
        comp0 = quick_sort(A, pivot_director=pd)

        self.assertEqual(A, [])
        self.assertEqual(comp0, 0)

        A = [1]    # single element
        comp1 = quick_sort(A, pivot_director=pd)
        self.assertEqual(A, [1])
        self.assertEqual(comp1, 0)

        B = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]    # even length
        comp2 = quick_sort(B, pivot_director=pd)
        """
        [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]  - 1,5,6->'5'
    '5' [5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6]  - 5 comparisons
        [4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6]  - done
        [4, 3, 1, 2]        - 4,3,2->'3'
    '3' [3, 4, 1, 2]        - 3 comparisons
    '3' [2, 1, 3, 4]        - done
    '1' [2, 1]              - 1 comparison
                            - Total = 5+3+1=9
        """
        self.assertEqual(B, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        self.assertEqual(comp2, 9)  # expected comparisons for pivot = 1st


def main(file_name):
    # take values from file and run quick_sort
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        if file_name[:4] == 'test':
            print((fh.readline()).strip())  # remove+show answer from test file
        o_data = list(map(int, [line.strip() for line in fh]))

        # populate a dict with all possible PivotMakers
#         m = sys.modules[__name__]
#         pivot_factories = {}
#         for module_attribute_name in dir(m):
#             module_attribute = getattr(m, module_attribute_name)
#             if inspect.isclass(module_attribute) and
#                 issubclass(module_attribute, PivotMaker) and
#                 module_attribute != PivotMaker:
#                 pivot_factories[module_attribute.name] = module_attribute

        pivot_factories = dict(
                          q1=PivotFirstElement(),
                          q2=PivotLastElement(),
                          q3=PivotMedianElement()
                          )

        for _, pf in sorted(pivot_factories.items()):
            A = deepcopy(o_data)
            pd = PivotDirector(pf)
            print("{1}, Pivoting Method: {2}, Comparisons: {0}".format(
                            quick_sort(A, pivot_director=pd),
                            *(pd.get_pivot_maker_data()))
                  )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # working with argv to accept file input
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: inv_count <file_name> (leave empty for testing)")
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("No filename input, testing...")
        unittest.main()
    # else: argv == 2
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Too many classes**

You have way too many classes, remember that if you have a class with just init and one other method it should be a standalone function.

**Swapping**

About swapping, do it the Pythonic way:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Using tuple unpacking.

**Over-engineering**

Also I fear you may be overthinking the quicksort problem, as it can be solved in 10 lines (more like 20) in a single function.

**Using higher order functions**

I think the worst problem in your code is the lack of higher order functions, that is, the pivoting selection method should be an argument to the quicksort function. I suggest an implementation like this:

```
def quicksort(list_, pivoting_decider):
    if len(list_) in (0, 1):
        return list_

    pivot = pivoting_decider(list_)

    smaller = [i for i in list_ if i < pivot]
    equal = [i for i in list_ if i == pivot]
    bigger = [i for i in list_ if i > pivot]

    return quicksort(smaller, pivoting_decider) +\
           equal +\
           quicksort(bigger, pivoting_decider)
```

The important thing is  noting that `pivoting_decider` is a function, so you can control the pivoting selection in a nice and short way, some examples are:

```
print(quicksort([5,7,2,2,6,8,1,0,], random.choice)) # Random
print(quicksort([5,7,2,2,6,8,1,0,], lambda list_: list_[0])) # First
print(quicksort([5,7,2,2,6,8,1,0,], lambda list_: list_[-1])) # Last
print(quicksort([5,7,2,2,6,8,1,0,], lambda list_: list_[len(list_)//2])) # Median
```

The best selection method is `random.choice`, as all deterministic selection methods are sensible to denial of service attacks where a malicious input list is given that makes quicksort behave quadratically.

Comment: If you'd be willing... I'd really like to see your 10 line version that implements the 3 pivoting methods ('first, last, median' was the assignment). The Pythonic swap is a good start. :)

Comment: @ofer.sheffer answer updated to answer your remark

Comment: thank you for the example. Great use of lambda to quickly write these higher order pivot_deciders. I hate to be a stickler after your effort, but your implementation is a bit slow (with 3 runs of list comprehensions and creating new lists with every recursion. The partition function (which can be just implemented in the main function) is meant to use swaps with a single run over the list. Regardless, your code is much faster to write and it gives me something to think about as far as writing with less thinking and less clutter. Programmer time counts as well at the end of the day. :)

Comment: Why `len(_list) in (0,1)` and not just `len(_list) <= 1`?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It is the same. Personal taste only.

Comment: Note: Immaterial of the great suggestion to cut down the pivot factory/maker classes and their director into 3 functions -- the requested Median of three (not the standard 'median') is mathematically interesting and greatly improves expected average results. The random case (best easy solution) wasn't requested, but is the "right" solution. Speed and memory-wise, it is preferable not to create many copies but to pass along indices into the recursion. Another thought: Multi-threading. Hoping to add it at a later date. Thanks again!